# UIViewController subclass to support both NIB loading and non

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm in the midst of creating a framework to be used internally, and I'm running into issues making a flexible view controller with a custom view.

The goal is to have an implementation similar to `UITableViewController`:

- If the view controller is initialized with a nib (or if a nib of the same name is found), it uses the outlets defined therein to define it's view. It is somewhat up to the developer to ensure the right subclass of `UIView` is used.
- If the view controller is initialized without a nib (or if no nib can be found), it creates it's own view, using the correct `UIView` subclass.

As a first stab, I overrode `-loadView` to create the custom view. This is what you would do if you weren't concerned with nibs, and it works great. However, if I try to load a nib (using, for example, `-initWithNibNamed:bundle:`) the `-loadView` method executes and the nib is ignored.

I've also tried using `-nibName` to determine if a nib name was passed, and this PARTIALLY works, but fails if `nil` was passed (which is still valid, and should absolutely still work if there is a nib of the same name as the view controller).

Keep in mind that I'm building a framework that will be used by other developers. "Flexible" and "Foolproof" are the keywords.

Any help at all would be more than I have now. Thanks much.

**Edit: Solved**

As was alluded to by @bunnyhero's suggestion below, checking for the availability of the nib during `-loadView` and attempting to recreate it's default implementation turned out to do the trick. I've settled on something like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    NSString *nib = self.nibName;
    NSBundle *bundle = self.nibBundle;
    if(!nib) nib = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
    if(!bundle) bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:nib ofType:@"nib"];

    if(path) {
            [bundle loadNibNamed:nib owner:self options:nil];
            return;
    }

    // Create custom view programmatically here.
}
```

Thanks @bunnyhero

Comment: It would help if you narrow to a specific question.

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of broad... Let me try to be more succinct: Is there a way to know if a view controller is loading a NIB (within the view lifecycle methods), OR is there a way to change the default class of a view controller's view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you combine your nibName nil check with a manual check for a nib with the same name as the view controller?

Maybe something like this (untested code off the top of my head):

```
if ([self nibName] != nil || [[self nibBundle] pathForResource:NSStringFromClass([self class]) ofType:@"xib"] != nil)
{
    // nib file exists...
}
```

I admit this is kind of crude and indirect :)

Comment: This is similar to the path I'm currently heading down. Thanks for validating my theory. I'll report back if I get it working the way I want. A bit of bonus trivia: Once compiled, nibs in the bundle have a `.nib` extension, rather than the pre-compiled `.xib`.